# put route return 500 error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to Update row on my db
I have been told that I need to create `PUT` route for this
So I did:

```
 Route::put('update/{id}/{done}', 'TasksController@update');
```

My Controller:

```
class TasksController extends Controller {

public function index(){
    DB::statement("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $todolist = DB::select('select * from todo');
    return $todolist;
}

public function update($id, $done){
    DB::update('update todo set done = ? where id = ?',[$done,$id]);
}
}
```

And I get this Error on java script console when I try to get `update/1/1` with ajax:

```
 (index):110 PUT http://localhost:8080/ex/ex/public/update/1/1 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

when I get to page from broswer I get:

```
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

And a list of files, What is the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: When interacting with browsers you are better of just using either get or post depending on the request.

Comment: did you tell your update form that it is an update method?

Comment: Browsers can't do PUT, do you have the hidden form field that tells Laravel to treat a POST like a PUT?

Comment: @MrCode Where is the error log? I check and all the names correct

Comment: @MrCode I look at the error log , there is nothing there, I look also in php_log also nothing, any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

here some advices : 
1. to update use patch not put 
2. make sure to add _token to your form
3. in your form add 'method' => 'PATCH'

Comment: Hey, I work with AJAX, I change the method to patch, Stil getting 500 error, any ideas?

Comment: can you post your ajax method ?

Comment: " in your form add 'method' => 'PATCH'" That really isn't supported by any browser I have ever encountrered.

Comment: its supported in laravel form helper

Comment: {!! Form::model($anything,['method'=>'PATCH','url'=>'update']) !!}